# Why am I getting different results between C++ and PHP SHA256 hashes?

Tags: php, c++, hash, sha256

I'm trying to generate a SHA256 hash in PHP which will be stored in a database and used for authentication by a C++ program.

In php the hash looks like this:

```
$mail = strtoupper(utf8_decode('tester@tester.com'));
$password = strtoupper(utf8_decode('password'));

$email = hash_init('sha256');
         hash_update($email, $mail);
$mail  = strtoupper(hash_final($email)); // In C++ the output is uppercase

$sha   = hash_init('sha256');
         hash_update($sha, $mail);
         hash_update($sha, ':');
         hash_update($sha, $password);
$pass  = hash_final($sha);
```

Or written another way:

```
$pass = hash('sha256', strtoupper(hash('sha256', $mail)).':'.$password);
```

In C++ the process looks like this:

```
Utf8ToUpperOnlyLatin(email);
Utf8ToUpperOnlyLatin(password);

SHA256Hash email;
email.UpdateData(name);
email.Finalize();

SHA256Hash sha;
sha.UpdateData(ByteArrayToHexStr(email.GetDigest(), email.GetLength()));
sha.UpdateData(":");
sha.UpdateData(password);
sha.Finalize();

return ByteArrayToHexStr(sha.GetDigest(), sha.GetLength(), true);
```

And the methods:

```
std::string ByteArrayToHexStr(uint8 const* bytes, uint32 arrayLen, bool reverse /* = false */)
{
    int32 init = 0;
    int32 end = arrayLen;
    int8 op = 1;

    if (reverse)
    {
        init = arrayLen - 1;
        end = -1;
        op = -1;
    }

    std::ostringstream ss;
    for (int32 i = init; i != end; i += op)
    {
        char buffer[4];
        sprintf(buffer, "%02X", bytes[i]);
        ss << buffer;
    }

    return ss.str();
}

bool Utf8ToUpperOnlyLatin(std::string& utf8String)
{
    std::wstring wstr;
    if (!Utf8toWStr(utf8String, wstr))
        return false;

    std::transform(wstr.begin(), wstr.end(), wstr.begin(), wcharToUpperOnlyLatin);

    return WStrToUtf8(wstr, utf8String);
}

SHA256Hash::SHA256Hash()
{
    SHA256_Init(&mC);
    memset(mDigest, 0, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * sizeof(uint8));
}

void SHA256Hash::UpdateData(const uint8 *dta, int len)
{
    SHA256_Update(&mC, dta, len);
}

void SHA256Hash::UpdateData(const std::string &str)
{
    UpdateData((uint8 const*)str.c_str(), str.length());
}

void SHA256Hash::Initialize()
{
    SHA256_Init(&mC);
}

void SHA256Hash::Finalize(void)
{
    SHA256_Final(mDigest, &mC);
}
```

The output using the two methods is:

```
C++: 09FEBAB417CF2FA563AC89963519CCAC53D5F556F8BF20D7EEB818A0584A514E
PHP: 4e514a58a018b8eed720bff856f5d553accc19359689ac63a52fcf17b4bafe09
```

And if I were to swap

```
$mail  = strtoupper(hash_final($email)); // In C++ the output is uppercase
```

for

```
$mail  = hash_final($email);
```

The PHP output would be

```
89ba15a964331258bcc763f44473c492854bf9c2694cc2306da64ccef8ffeab2
```

Why can't I seem to get PHP and C++ to produce the same result?

Thank you.

Comment: To add a little clarification, I would like PHP to produce the same result that I get using my C++ methods.

Comment: In your C++ implementation, you have a "reverse" parameter, which is set to true for the final output. In the first pair of outputs, the two are different because the C++ one is reversed. Seems to be right, am I missing something?

Comment: Geoffliu, write that as an answer so I can accept it. That is indeed correct. I can't believe I missed that! Too many hours, not enough coffee :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ implementation used the inverse of the bytes returned by the hash. Both methods were correct, but the outputs did not match do to a minor oversight. Thanks to Geoffliu for pointing that out.